# What does this mean:- pnp 00:06: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0303 (active)

Tags: 64-bit, suspend

After suspend mode i get an error : Device 00:06 failed to resume: error -19. After trying dmesg | grep 00:06 i got the following output:

*[    0.732074] pnp 00:06: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0303 (active)*

[20688.139383] PM: Device 00:06 failed to resume: error -19

[21037.424197] PM: Device 00:06 failed to resume: error -19

Answer (score 0):

The error is related to Keyboard/Touchpad controller(i8042). Since kernel version 2.6.31, the script that was used to unbind the devices on suspend and rebind them on resume does not work. According to [this](http://lightrush.ndoytchev.com/random-1/i8042quirkoptions) link, the system uses ACPIPnP / PnPBIOS to discover KBD/AUX controllers and hence the error message.
You can use the following workaround to get rid of the error message.

Open terminal and run

```
 sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

- Change the line ***GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""*** to 
  ***GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="i8042.nopnp"***
- Save and close.

Update GRUB

```
sudo update-grub
```

- Restart your PC.